# Mapping model value expression that can map to a related (to-one) relationship

Tags: core-data

Can you access related (to-one) attributes using value expressions in Core Data mapping models?

```
Example: newEntityAttribute = $source.toOneRelationship.oldEntityAttribute
```

It's not working for me at the moment (newEntityAttribute is being set to nil) so I'd like to see what can be done. I'm wondering if this can be done just with a mapping model without using NSEntityMigrationPolicy.

Here's an example:

I've got 2 entities which are related which I'd like to flatten into one:

```
Owner - attributes: ownerName, pets
Pet - attributes: petName, owner
```

This is just an example and not the real scenario.

Using a mapping model, I want to map these 2 entities into a single entity that looks like this:

```
Pet - attributes: petName, ownerName
```

I've created a mapping model which looks like this:

```
Pet Attribute Mappings:
Destination    Value Expression
-------------------------------
petName        $source.petName
ownerName      $source.owner.ownerName
```

The problem is that ownerName is always resulting in nil.

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Expressions work with keypaths and it's a simple keypath. Devils always in the details, however.

Comment: Very strange, it's definitely not working and I've tried lots of times. I've had to resort to subclassing NSEntityMigrationPolicy.

Comment: Can't say, the question doesn't have enough realistic detail for me to advise further. The setup you have should work, that is all I can tell you.